# How to make a public method that is not inherited by subclasses?

Tags: actionscript-3, scope

As the question states, I want to know how I can make a function in a class that other classes can access, but subclasses cannot. I have a class that has some public getters and setters that I want my document class to have access to call, but I don't want the subclass to have these functions because they'd be useless on the subclass.

For example

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public function SomeClass() {}
    public function notInherited():void { trace("Not inherited"; }
}

public class OtherClass extends SomeClass 
{
     public function OtherClass() 
     {
     notInherited(); //Want this to return an error
     } 
}

public class HasAccess 
{
     public function HasAccess() 
     {
     notInherited(); //Not inherited
     }
}
```

I know this probably has something to do with custom namespaces, but after searching up about them I still don't really have much understanding of how they work. That's about it; thanks for reading.

Comment: You can't, what you describe if having any class access to those methods except the subclasses. That's impossible in any language, if a method has public access (and internal is a form of public access) then that public access can't be denied to any other class and I should add completely irrelevant to even try to implement. If that method has no effect on subclasses then let it have no effect has long as those methods can't be overriden why would you care so much.

Comment: @BotMaster To be clear for the OP, using `internal` *does* limit access to sub-classes *in the same package*, while sub-classes in a different package will *not* have access. I'm sure this is what you meant.

Comment: This is still far from fitting the bill and the effects will not affect subclasses only but all classes. All classes and subclasses in same package will have access, all classes and subclasses outside package will not have access, quite a difference. Since those methods have no effects on subclasses then marking them final should be enough.

Comment: Why would they be useless on the subclass? Please provide the concreat example. It sounds very much like inheritance is the wrong tool for your job.

Comment: I have a Force class that has as a get/set function for whether it's angle property is static or not, i.e. whether or not that property can be changed by the user. However for my Weight class, which inherits Force, it's angle will always be the same and can't be changed by the user, so I don't want my Weight to have this method as it would be useless since it's angle will always be the same whether or not it can be changed.

If my weight class inherits the useless method, in my mind it seems like a wasted use of memory consumption, which I know is a bit pedantic but I want to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this quite in the general terms you've asked, but you can do this if you put your document class and your other class in the same package and use `internal` instead of `public`, and you put your sub-class in a different package. The `internal` keyword limits access to classes in the same package.

Example (notice the `package` statements):

```
package main {
    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public function Main() {
            var stuff:Stuff = new Stuff();
            stuff.doStuff();
        }
    }
}

package main {
    public class Stuff {
        internal function doStuff():void { }
    }
}

package other {
    public class OtherStuff extends Stuff {
        public function OtherStuff() {
            // no access to this.doStuff()
        }
    }
}
```

---

As for [using a namespace](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/namespaces.html), this can be a good option to make the intent of your code more clear, but it doesn't actually limit access in any new way, it just requires access to be more deliberate: while the `namespace` *does* hide visibility of the API to anyone who doesn't use the namespace, anyone *can* use the namespace and have access to the API without any additional limits (ie `public`, `internal` and `protected`).

Still, this may be all you are after. Here's an example which uses a public namespace and no packages:

```
// my_stuff.as
package {
    public namespace my_stuff;
}

// Stuff.as
package {
    public class Stuff {
        my_stuff function doStuff():void { }
    }
}

// Main.as
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
        public function Main() {
            use namespace my_stuff; // you can put this above the class to give the entire class access to the namespace
            var stuff:Stuff = new Stuff();
            stuff.doStuff();
        }
    }
}

// OtherStuff.as
package {
    public class OtherStuff extends Stuff {
        public function OtherStuff() {
            this.doStuff(); // not allowed

            this.my_stuff::doStuff(); // allowed

            // also allowed
            use namespace my_stuff;
            this.doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that if your namespace is in a package, ex `package stuff { public namespace my_stuff }`, you must import the namespace just like a class, for example: `import stuff.my_stuff`)

Comment: Ah I see. Could you possibly expand a bit more; what do you mean by 'deliberate'?

Comment: @NotAPro I was on mobile earlier. I've just now edited my answer to elaborate on what I meant by "deliberate", and provided examples.